# Magento-2 : How I can move terms and condition from payment to custom step checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout, terms-and-conditions

Magento-2 is displaying terms and condition on payment step. but I want to move it from payment step to my custom review step.

How can I display it on custom step?

See my reference screen shots.

[image: Currently showing on payment step]

[image: I want to display like this on my custom step]

Custom step `checkout_index_index.xml`

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="checkout" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="checkout_cart_item_renderers"/>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <!-- The new step you add -->
                                        <item name="my-new-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">ThinkIdeas_Checkoutsteps/js/view/my-step-view</item>
                                            <!--To display step content before shipping step "sortOrder" value should be < 1-->
                                            <!--To display step content between shipping step and payment step  1 < "sortOrder" < 2 -->
                                            <!--To display step content after payment step "sortOrder" > 2 -->
                                            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">3</item>
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <!--add here child component declaration for your step-->
                                                <item name="review-payment-method" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">ThinkIdeas_Checkoutsteps/js/view/payment-information</item>
                                                    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">review-payment-method</item>
                                                </item>

                                                <item name="review-shipping-address" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">ThinkIdeas_Checkoutsteps/js/view/shipping-information</item>
                                                    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">review-shipping-address</item>
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="ship-to" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping-information/list</item>
                                                            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">ship-to</item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>

                                                <item name="review-billing-address" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">ThinkIdeas_Checkoutsteps/js/view/billing-information</item>
                                                    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">review-billing-address</item>
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="bill-to" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">ThinkIdeas_Checkoutsteps/js/view/billing-information/list</item>
                                                            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">bill-to</item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Default file :

> vendor/magento/module-checkout-agreements/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="billing-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="payment" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="payments-list" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="before-place-order" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="agreements" xsi:type="array">
                                                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_CheckoutAgreements/js/view/checkout-agreements</item>
                                                                            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">100</item>
                                                                            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">before-place-order</item>
                                                                            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">checkoutAgreements</item>
                                                                            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                                                        </item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                        <item name="additional-payment-validators" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="agreements-validator" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_CheckoutAgreements/js/view/agreement-validation</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Used by this code terms and condition is display but validation not working.

Comment: Hey, I am trying the same, did you find a solution to it?

Comment: Not getting any solution so I skipped this. You can apply below answer solution may be it will help you.

Comment: @SureshChikani Have you got any solution for the add terms and coondition to custom checkout step?

Answer (score 1):

You need to override this layout file:

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout-agreements/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml
```

and change `before-place-order` node to your custom step node.

```
<item name="before-place-order" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="agreements" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_CheckoutAgreements/js/view/checkout-agreements</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">0</item>
            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">before-place-order</item>
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">checkoutAgreements</item>
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
        </item>
    </item>
</item>
```

You will also need to make changes in the html file where this code is written:

```
<!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('before-place-order') -->
   <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
<!--/ko-->
```

and change `before-place-order` to your custom step node.

Comment: I know that but how can I display in my custom step?

Comment: see my updated answer

Comment: @SHPatel change <item name="displayArea">Your Cstom Step Area</item>

Comment: @SejalShah see my updated question.

Comment: I dont see the "Magento_CheckoutAgreements/js/view/checkout-agreements" node in your layout file.